# What is the difference between "service restart" and "service reload"

Tags: server, services, postgresql

I'm trying to understand the difference between `service restart [someservice]` and `service reload [someservice]`. I understand that `restart` restarts the service whereas `reload` reloads the configuration. But I don't understand the practical implications of this well enough to determine which I should use in a given context.

An example: most guides I've read for setting up PostgreSQL say that, once I've edited `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connections, I should run:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

However, if I were to guess which to use based on the description above, I would choose `reload`.

In case it matters, I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, though I'm hoping for an as generally applicable explanation as possible.

Comment: A couple years ago, I was running a server with several thousand users. restarting Apache wasn’t fast for whatever reason, it would take about 3 minutes to restart apache(reasons). Anyhow,  if the server was down for 3 minutes my boss would get about 800 phone calls.  With service reload, 0 phone calls. Thats the difference.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you said is correct, `reload` tells the service to reload its configuration files. That means it should be sufficient to reload the configuration; however there may be certain services that "don't follow the rule" or that won't reload config files. Due to this you're probably safer with `restart`. I personally do not use `postgresql`, so I don't know.

Comment: Meanwhile, there is `reload-or-restart`

Comment: For PostgreSQL, you can apply changes to the /etc/postgresql/version/main/postgresql.conf with a reload. Applying changes to pg_hba.conf requires a restart.

Comment: @Suuuehgi where is `reload-or-restart` documented please?

Comment: @WillSheppard You find the manual by `man systemctl` or [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html).
_Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, stop and then start them instead. If the units are not running yet, they will be started._

Answer (score 87):

- **restart** = stop + start
- **reload** = remain running + re-read configuration files.

Answer (score 12):

Not all services support `reload`.  For those that do, it is usually preferable to restarting (i.e. reloading causes less or no downtime).

[The Debian Policy Manual specifies](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-writing-init) that every `/etc/init.d/` script should support a `force-reload` action, which means `reload` if the service supports it, and `restart` if the service doesn't support reloading.

I'm not sure how that translates into the modern Ubuntu upstart world.

Comment: The Debian Policy Manual was really useful link, thanks.

Comment: most support reload, if not through the system service, thought  /etc/init.d/SomeProgram  reload

Comment: For the sake of using "systemctl reload-or-restart someService"...... Reload will be done if the .service file (check with systemctl status <service> ) ... contains the "ExecReload" directive. If this doesn't exist in that file, then a reload will be skipped and a restart will be done.

Answer (score 5):

To expand [عبد النور التومي](https://askubuntu.com/users/159179/abdennour-toumi) answer with my experience with systemd.

In systemd whenever a process is started it is run within systemd context, most clear example of this is with the environment variables defined in its unit file.

So when you send a `systemctl reload [someservice]` signal it sends a signal to the service to reload itself gracefully if it is supported. If not, the process will simply ignore the signal. This is configurable though.

What do I mean with gracefully? to start new workers with the new configuration or code and stop the old workers as they finish serving current requests if any.

And if you make `systemctl restart [someservice]` it will tell systemctl to tell the service to stop, destroy the current systemd context, create a new one and run the service again. This makes sense for example to reload environment variables in a systemd context or if a reload is not supported.

Hope this clarifies a little and if I'm wrong in something please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

*Signal* detail may be important for reload.
Most of times it is all about sending a proper signal (SIGHUP) to service process. If the underlying application has some kind of 'live configuration re-apply' strategy, then most probably there should be a line starting with "ExecReload=" in the service unit file. Which means reload is optional and you need to check if the application implements reload: (docker i.e.)

```bsh
cat $(echo $(systemctl show -p FragmentPath docker) | cut -d "=" -f 2)
```

Restart is just stop-start. Systemd only needs to know proper "ExecStart" command to start.

Answer (score 0):

currently if a service needs kicking (e.g. a config file changed) you can notify the service, but this leads to a restart. It would be nice if a reload was done if the service was already running (although I suppose there are bound to be some services which require restarts for some files, reloads for others).

The most complex example I can think of is something like Apache. Normally you can just ask it to reload, however sometimes you need to request a restart instead (if you add/remove modules for example).

Answer (score 0):

postgres is a good example for big differences between reload and restart, because the later has to disconnect all database-clients.

when the connections should not rollback, you can stop the service without a "--force" at first by using **pg_ctlcluster**.

in **/etc/postgres/{version}/{dbname}/postgresql.conf** and at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/ every parameter has a remark like "This parameter can only be set at server start."